# Variables de un script en otro

Tags: python, funciones

quiero agregar una tarea nueva a un programa realizado por otra persona

el otro programa esta compuesto por varios archivos que trabajan en conjunto, pero solo necesito  modificar un archivo el cual contiene únicamente una matriz con  valores que utiliza para el calculo (nombre del archivo **caso30**)

```
from numpy import matrix
GD = matrix('   1   0.0     0        0          0       1       ;'
             '  2   0.0     0       -0.4        0.5     1       ;'
             '  5   0       0       -0.4        0.4     1       ;'
             '  8   0       0       -0.1        0.4     1       ;'
             '  11  0       0       -0.06       0.24    1       ;'
             '  13  0       0       -0.06       0.24    1        ')
```

posteriormente otros archivos utilizan estos valores para trabajar

mi programa calcula valores óptimos y les asigna variables dentro de funcion **Calc** (el programa es muy largo y no puedo ponerlo todo), nombre del archivo **ventana**

```
def Calc():
    P_Barra_1 = resultados_m [0]
    P_Barra_2 = resultados_m [1]
    P_Barra_3 = resultados_m [2]
    P_Barra_4 = resultados_m [3]
    P_Barra_5 = resultados_m [4]
    P_Barra_6 = resultados_m [5]
```

deseo reemplazar los valores de la primera columna de la matriz con los resultados de mi programa

```
from numpy import matrix
GD = matrix('   1   0.0     0        0          0       1       ;'
             '  2   0.0     0       -0.4        0.5     1       ;'
             '  5   0       0       -0.4        0.4     1       ;'
             '  8   0       0       -0.1        0.4     1       ;'
             '  11  0       0       -0.06       0.24    1       ;'
             '  13  0       0       -0.06       0.24    1        ')

GD [0,0]= P_Barra_1
GD [1,0]= P_Barra_2
GD [2,0]= P_Barra_3 
GD [3,0]= P_Barra_4
GD [4,0]= P_Barra_5
GD [5,0]= P_Barra_6
```

no se como hacer para que el otro archivo lea las variables de mi programa P_Barra_1,2,3,...

Answer (score 1):

Si entiendo bien lo que quieres, deseas que el *módulo `caso30`* tenga otros valores para `GD`. No dices si quieres que los valores sean *persistentes* o sólo para la *sesión*. En el primer caso, no queda otra que modificar el fichero python.

Pero en el caso de que sólo sea para la sesión, hay un truco: la importación de módulos en python está optimizada y sólo se realiza la primera vez. El resto de veces usa el módulo ya importado.

Haz que tu programa principal importe el módulo antes y cambia lo que necesites:

```
import caso30

caso30.GD [0,0]= P_Barra_1
caso30.GD [1,0]= P_Barra_2
caso30.GD [2,0]= P_Barra_3 
caso30.GD [3,0]= P_Barra_4
caso30.GD [4,0]= P_Barra_5
caso30.GD [5,0]= P_Barra_6

# Llama al resto de módulos

import modulo2

modulo2.run()
```

Aunque `modulo2` importe de nuevo `caso30`, verá como `caso30.GD` la matriz que se ha modificado.